# Для чего нужен код (хэштег) в конце сайта?

Tags: html, url, веб-программирование

Последнее время заметил код (или хэштег) в адресной строке в конце многих сайтов. 
К примеру: `https://site.ru/blablabla/#.V49UWuLLfK4`

Причем при каждом обновлении страницы он меняется, а ссылка работает и без него.
Особенно этим грешит `medium.com`. Для чего это нужно и как это сделать?

Только не пишите про якори. Это не они.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Эта часть URL называется "идентификатор фрагмента" ([fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)). Кусок URL, извлечь смысл из которого должен **клиент**, а не сервер. Поэтому, запрашивая документ по HTTP, клиент может эту часть в запросе даже не передавать (возможно, даже обязан не передавать, но надо глянуть в стандарт). Это семантически и высокоуровнево.

Поначалу (и уже довольно давно) эта часть использовалась только для якорей в браузерах. Сервер возвращает весь документ, а клиент смотрит в фрагмент, ищет соответствующий якорь и **проскролливает вид до него** исключительно ради удобства пользователя. Это вы знаете.

С распространением JavaScript к этой части появился доступ не только у браузера, но и у **произвольного кода**, присланного сервером. И эта часть стала неплохим местом для хранения небольшого кусочка клиентских данных, о которых серверу знать необязательно, а клиент как-то может отреагировать. Для чего? Ну, для всего, что умеет JavaScript, нужно только применить воображение.

---

Сейчас это применяется для хранения состояния в небольших SPA прямо внутри ссылки. *Это необязательно должен быть именно SPA, это может быть любое браузерное приложение на JS, возможно даже размещённое на нескольких страницах. Просто это короткий термин и понятно о чём.*

Ссылку клиент А может послать клиенту Б какими-то своими способами, и, открыв её, можно увидеть приложение точно в том же состоянии, в каком оно было у клиента А. Пример: [Coriolis.io, инструмент для обмена сборками кораблей в Elite: Dangerous](https://coriolis.io/outfit/federal_dropship/06D6D5A5D6D4D4C---------01----2i2f.Iw18aQ==.Aw18aQ==).

Ещё вариация — хранение не всего состояния приложения, а только той части, которая может быть полезна другим пользователям.

Например, роутинг. URL вида `http://site.com/#/thing/42` Он осуществлялся в основном через фрагментную часть. Это пока не было **HTML5 History API**. Теперь есть. И теперь когда сервер можно научить понимать любые URL, можно писать SPA, меняющие "текущий URL" в пределах одной страницы без подобных костылей. [AngularJS без "HTML5 mode"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes) работает таким образом. Когда программируемой серверной части нет (или её лень настроить, что бывает), это единственный способ клиентского роутинга, который не ломает получающиеся ссылки: ведь фрагментную часть сервер игнорирует.

Или обмен токенами. Некогда было засилье мессенджеров, работающих через WebRTC, и через фрагментный кусок образовывались **комнаты**. SPA ищет там **токен комнаты**, если не находит — генерирует случайный и добавляет его туда. Пользователю остаётся только скинуть ссылку. Перешедшие по ней попадут в SPA, а JS-клиент в нём увидит токен и сразу попросится в указанную комнату, попав к тому, кто ссылку скинул.